# Updating to OS X 10.10.2 broke Quick Look previews for HTML files

Tags: macos, quicklook, html

After updating to OS X 10.10.2, I can no longer use Quick Look on HTML files – I just get a blank preview window, and the issue persists through a reboot. But all other files types work fine.

Is there a cache I can clear or something else I can try to get this working again?

Comment: I have the same problem and reported it to Apple as a bug.

Comment: This is also affecting SVG files, since they use the same webkit renderer as html files.

Answer (score 3):

Known bug on Apple's Bug Radar as Bug # 19639311

[10.10.2 quick look broken for HTML files](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6803599)

`qlmanage -t <path_to_html_file>` produces a small thumbnail of the HMTL file
`qlmanage -p <path_to_html_file>` just gives me a blank quicklook preview

This doesn't happen with a .jpg file I used as a control sample.

Comment: I submitted a bug report a few days ago and they just closed it as a duplicate of the same issue. Hopefully there's enough duplicates that they'll fix it in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the quicklook cache by entering this in terminal:

- `qlmanage -r`
- `qlmanage -r cache`

I have the same problem after updating, but clearing cache doesn't seem to help.